# How to create a milestone using upworks api, the one defined in their api gives an authorization error

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I used the nodejs upwork api via npm package (node-upwork) to create an hourly job with Upwork.offers.makeOffer api call which works fine. However,  while creating a 'fixed-price' job it is requried to create a `milestone` object and set job_type to 'fixed-price'. Doing this on the same request gives an error => 'signature verification error'.
What could be the issue?
Here is an example of the Object that I am creating for the request

```
    var Offers = require('upwork-api/lib/routers/hr/clients/offers.js').Offers;
    var offers = new Offers(api);
var params = {
  title: 'RM 1',
  job_type: 'fixed-price',
  charge_rate: 15,
  message_to_contractor: 'Please accept this test job from Task Router',
  contractor_key: '~01be12345c1234534b',
  'context[job_posting_ref]': '~12345d3348af3dc' 
};
var milestone = {
    milestone_description : "complete the job",
    deposit_amount : 1,
    due_date : '01-17-2017'
};
params.milestones = [milestone];
offers.makeOffer(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("offer has been made");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears upwork requires a flat JSON object. Their API docs notes that all data must be sent as RAW post data. So you would have to provide the milestone information like this.

```
var params = {
  title: 'RM 1',
  job_type: 'fixed-price',
  charge_rate: 15,
  message_to_contractor: 'Please accept this test job from Task Router',
  contractor_key: '~01be12345c1234534b',
  'context[job_posting_ref]': '~12345d3348af3dc',
  'milestones[0][milestone_description]': 'complete the job 1',
  'milestones[0][deposit_amount]': 15.0,
  'milestones[0][due_date]': '01-10-2017'
};
```